# Android - Customizing the Spinner widget Look and Feel

Tags: android-widget, android, android-custom-view

Is it possible to change the color of the `radio button` in the Android **spinner widget**. By default it displays the green color for the radio button.

I need to change it to **some other** color, is it possible, and how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is an old question now, but here goes...

You will need to create a custom Theme and apply it to the Activity with your spinner.

First, you need to create images for the checked/unchecked states of the 'new' radio, you could just pull the given images `btn_radio_on.png` and `btn_radio_off.png` from the sdk's `res/drawable-*` folder(s). Edit them to look how you want (such as changing color or whatever) and save off to your project.

Next, create a new xml file in your `res/values` folder, and add the following:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomSpinnerRadioTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/EditedRadio</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditedRadio" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:checkMark">@drawable/edited_radio</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then, create another xml file in `res/drawable` named `edited_radio.xml`, and it should contain the following:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_radio_on" />
</selector>
```

just be sure to reference your edited images for the checked states. Then you just have to apply the `CustomSpinnerRadioTheme` to your Activity and run!

A good resource I found is [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) especially the additional reference on [Android Styles (styles.xml)](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml) and [Android Themes (themes.xml)](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml)