# How to make custom Spinner pop-up list radio button on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am able to customize the spinner dropdown background by specifying the drawable resource in the Spinner XML element:

```
<Spinner 
 android:id="@+id/search_spinner" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/spinner_dropdown">
</Spinner>
```

Once the spinner drop down is clicked the pop-up list with options appears. This I am able to customize as well by calling the `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_row_layout);` where the `spinner_row_layout` is the layout for one line for the list. If I put here a `TextView` I have the custom row, but I miss the radio button on the right side. If I put there instead of the `TextView` the `CheckedTextView` I have custom background for the line, but the default check mark. The problem with the default checkmark is that its color do not fit the company color guidlines...

How can I define the custom check mark - ideally by using styles/themes for the whole application? I have tried many ways including this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177700/android-customizing-the-spinner-widget-look-and-feel), but nothing works. If anyone has the working example please share.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define the custom row layout for your spinner.

This row layout can have a `TextView` and the `CheckBox`. You can always further customize this.

I am have not tried this out myself yet. (I have to do this for a project ended up in your question) I found a good example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html).