# How to Customize spinner view?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to customize Spinner. selector in spinner not looking proper in Mobile.any help will appreciated.

Comment: write the custom adapter and inflate your xml ......

Comment: [Let me do it for you](http://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=custom+spinner+android)

Comment: Depends upon what you want to customize in spinner? spinner dropdownlist or array items of spinner ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177700/android-customizing-the-spinner-widget-look-and-feel

Comment: i want to change apperance of spinner?

Comment: @lalitPoptani you really did it. +1.