# How do I apply a style to all spinners of an Android application

Tags: android, styles, spinner

Applying a button style to entire app:

```
<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
</style>
```

but how do you do for a spinner? I want to do it like in my example...and substitute spinner ..i.e: "android:spinnerStyle" ?

Comment: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/03/easily-create-a-default-custom-styled-spinner-android/ Goto to the above link for Custom Style spinner examples .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Customizing the Spinner widget Look and Feel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177700/android-customizing-the-spinner-widget-look-and-feel)

Comment: Yes I've seen that link. It uses the manifest to add a theme. I want to do it like in my example...and substitute spinner.

Comment: Its not a duplicate . The link you reference concerns the spinner drop down. I need the actual spinner widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manifest:

```
<application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_new"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ApplicationStyle"
```

style.xml:

```
<style name="holoSpinner" parent="@android:style/Theme">
      <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_holo_sel</item>
      <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#959494</item>
      <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
      <item name="android:paddingTop">8dip</item>
      <item name="android:paddingBottom">8dip</item>
      <item name="android:paddingRight">12dip</item>
      <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dip</item>
    </style>

<style name="ApplicationStyle" parent="android:Theme">
           <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/holoSpinner</item>
           <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
           <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/holoEditText</item>
        </style>
```